# How to do a BFS on a verb phrase and extract all the dependent(first level or immediate dependent) noun tags in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, graph, tree, nlp, stanford-nlp

[image]

In this dependency tree I want to do one level BFS and extract a structure where VP/VBZ is the root node and the dependent NP/ NNP are the child nodes.
How can I parse the tree like this? Please help.

E.g, "makes" is the VP/VBZ then the immediate dependent Noun phrases are Bell and Products. Then suppose "electronic" were another verb phrase then I want to extract computer and building which are NPs.